# A question about an ideal in power series ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ denotes the ring of infinite sequences over rational, written by vectors $\bar{s}=(a_1,a_2,\cdots).$

In the power series ring $R[[x]]$, a general element is of type $\bar{s}_0 + \bar{s}_2x + \bar{s}_2x^2+\cdots $, so it is a power series in $x$ with coefficients the vectors/sequences over rationals.

Let $I$ denote the ideal of $R$ generated by 
$$\bar{e}_1=(1,0,\cdots), e_2=(0,1,\cdots),\cdots. $$
So $I$ contains sequences which are zero after finite steps.

Let $IR[[x]]$ denote the ideal in $R[[x]]$ generated by set $I$.

**Q.** I do not understand why $I[[x]]$ is bigger than $IR[[x]]$?

(I confused with elements of finite support in both ideals. )

Comment: $I[[X]]$ contains $\sum e_iX^i$. Is that in $IR[[X]]$?

Comment: OK, this is fine. With a little thinking, I came to following. An arbitrary element of $IR[[x]]$ is a power series in $x$ whose coefficients come from a *finitely generated ideal of $R$*; but as your examples shows, this element has coefficients, not coming from a finitely generated ideal of $R$. Am I right?